# Does a group homomorphism always produce a group extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We all know the very famous group isomorphism theorems:
If $\varphi:G \rightarrow H$ is a group homomorphism them $G/\ker(\varphi)$ is isomorphic to $im(\varphi)$.

If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a covering map, we can think of $X$ as being a discrete fibre bundle over $Y$.

It seem as if a similar thing might happen with groups. There is a Wikipedia page for group extension https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension. Is this notion useful, can thinking about group homomorphism like this help? If so can you provide a good example where this is used, or some consequence of view the group this way?

Comment: You might find this post at Terrence Tao's blog an interesting read https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/07/10/cayley-graphs-and-the-geometry-of-groups/

Comment: "But is this notion useful. " Why not? It is very useful.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment @MikeF.

Comment: The comment refers to the wikipedia page on group extensions, which is useful. Perhaps you could clarify what you mean by "this notion" to avoid "vacuous" comments (I just thought you ask whether the notion of group extensions is useful here, but I have misunderstood you, I think).

Comment: Ah okay I see, I apologise. I mis read your comment, I thought you were trying to be cheeky. I'll delete my previous response.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you meant by saying "is this notion usefull" or what exactly you were adressing. However, in order to adress the question in your title:

*Any* group homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to G'$ gives rise to a short exact sequence (canonical decomposition) $$0\to \ker \varphi\xrightarrow{i} G\xrightarrow{\varphi} \operatorname{im} \varphi\to 0$$
which is, by definition, precisely a group extension of $\operatorname{im}\varphi$ by $\ker \varphi$.

By the first isomorphism theorem this is (up to isomorphism) essentially $$0\to \ker \varphi\xrightarrow{i} G \xrightarrow{\pi} G\big/\ker\varphi\to 0$$ where $\pi$ denotes the canonical projection map.

In a similar manner you can always consider the direct product $G = N\times H$ of two groups $N,H$ together with the canonical inclusion $N\hookrightarrow N\times H$ and projection $N\times H\twoheadrightarrow H$ respectively, which provides $$0\to N\hookrightarrow N\times H \twoheadrightarrow H \to 0$$

Why is this usefull? For instance, suppose you are given a long exact sequence of $R$-modules $M_i$ $$\cdots \to M_i \xrightarrow{\phi_i} M_{i+1}\xrightarrow{\phi_{i+1}}M_{i+2}\to \cdots$$

the canonical decomposition allows you to extract short exact sequences by passing to the kernels and cokernels

$$0\to \operatorname{coker} \phi_{i-1}\to M_i \to \ker \phi_{i+1} \to 0$$

and this is used extensivelly in the algebraic machinery of algebraic topology whenever we are relating, for instance, the homology of a chain complex $(C_\bullet, \partial_\bullet)$ with the (co)homology of the dualized complex $(\operatorname{Hom}(C_\bullet),G))$ or similarly in the case of the complex $(C_\bullet,\partial_\bullet)$ after applying the $-\otimes G$ functor.

One particular result that immediately comes to my mind is the universal coefficient theorem for homology.